# jQuery Mobile causes Access Denied in jQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features) on adding mobile features to an ASP.Net MVC 4 application.

When I launch the application (causing the Login page to be loaded), I get `Access denied` at the following point in jQuery 1.7.2 (also reproduced with 1.7.1)

```
if ( elem.parentNode ) { // Access denied here, Line 6081
    elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
}
```

Walking down the call stack, I see the following in jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js (there are a few other methods on the call stack as well)

```
// Called from .initializePage:
if ( !$pages.length ) {
    $pages = $( "body" ).wrapInner( "<div data-" + $.mobile.ns + "role='page'></div>" ).children( 0 ); // Called from here, Line 7475
}

// First method in jquery.mobile:
if( $.mobile.autoInitializePage ){
    $.mobile.initializePage();  // Called from here, Line 7541
}
```

If I comment out jquery.mobile from my application, it works as it did previously:

```
// _Layout.cshtml:
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All JavaScript files are being served via the built-in VS2010 web server from the main project's domain.

**UPDATE**

Upon further inspection, I realize this is what jQuery Mobile is doing when the error happens:

```
// find and enhance the pages in the dom and transition to the first page.
// if no pages are found, create one with body's inner html
$pages = $( "body" ).wrapInner( "<div data-" + $.mobile.ns + "role='page'></div>" ).children( 0 );
```

What's happening to cause jquery.mobile to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a reference to a third party script on the page ([Comodo SSL](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1319&nav=0,1,82) validation) that certainly did not need to be on a mobile version of the page.  jQuery Mobile tried to manipulate the related DOM, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've been searching for days why the popup method (JQuery Mobile) didn't work on an .aspx page. Visual Studio automatically initializes the page with a scriptmanager.

The solution was to comment out the following line in the Asp:Scriptmanager tag, since it is conflicting with the JQuery reference in the head of the page:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
```